# Azure AD Groups and User Assigned Managed Identities

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

How do you allow User Assigned Managed Identities(UAMI) to R/W Azure AD Groups ?
I have a .Net Core 3.1 Azure Function app running as a UMAI. The app needs to be able to R/W Azure AD Groups. I have the code running via an App Registration Service Principal on my laptop. In Azure a UAMI is a Subscription contributor and is associated to the FunctionApp.

This works local and in Azure:

```
        var azureFluentClient = AzureAuthenticator.AzureFluentClient(context._ILogger, context.ExecutionContext,context.Settings);
        var resourceGroups = await azureFluentClient.ResourceGroups.ListAsync();
```

Works local, FAILS on Azure:

```
        var azureFluentClient = AzureAuthenticator.AzureFluentClient(context._ILogger, context.ExecutionContext, context.Settings);
        var groups = await azureFluentClient.AccessManagement.ActiveDirectoryGroups.GetByNameAsync("AAA1");
```

Error:

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."},"requestId":"f797cb42-a75d-48d9-a902-c580955800cd","date":"2020-07-10T05:41:59"}}

ex.Response.Content: "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

Microsoft.Azure.Management.Graph.RBAC.Fluent.Models.GraphErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Graph.RBAC.Fluent.GroupsOperations.ListWithHttpMessagesAsync(ODataQuery`1 odataQuery, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Graph.RBAC.Fluent.GroupsOperationsExtensions.ListAsync(IGroupsOperations operations, ODataQuery`1 odataQuery, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Graph.RBAC.Fluent.ActiveDirectoryGroupsImpl.<ListAsync>b__7_0(CancellationToken cancellation)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.PagedCollection`2.LoadPageWithWrapModelAsync(Func`2 listInnerAsync, Func`3 listInnerNext, Func`3 wrapModelAsync, Boolean loadAllPages, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.PagedCollection`2.LoadPage(Func`2 listInnerAsync, Func`3 listInnerNext, Func`2 wrapModel, Boolean loadAllPages, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Graph.RBAC.Fluent.ActiveDirectoryGroupsImpl.ListAsync(Boolean loadAllPages, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at HDIManagement.FunctionApp.API.TestServiceConfiguration.TestADGroupAccess(OperationsContext context) in C:\Users\josep\source\repos\HDI\BareMetal\HDI-Logging\HDIManagement.FunctionApp\API\TestConfiguration.cs:line 67
```

The difference is there is an App Registration used for local runs which has **API permissions: Azure Active Directory Graph/Directory.ReadWrite.All**. I think the problem is there is no App Registration associated with UAMI's so there is no way to grant the permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
FunctionApp's User Assigned Managed Identity(UAMI) requires

- Assign UAMI Subscription Contributor Role (my code does more than line just look for AAD Groups)
- Assign UAMI AD Directory Readers role (acceptable in a production environment)
- Add UAMI as Owner to AD Groups to be manipulated (Add/Remove members)

Note, UAMI will not be able to create, assign, delete or manage any AD Groups not specifically granted permission by virtue of Ownership.

*I spent significant time in due to AD delays/caching to changes made to the Managed Identity (changes could take a while to appear, fooling me into rabbit holes).* I wrote this script to help determine the **actual** requirements of my FunctionApp. After running this script, I run my FunctionApp test method. Since Identity is new each time, there is no caching or delayed implementation.

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount -TenantId $tenantId
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $tenantId

Set-AzureRmContext  -TenantId $tenantId -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

#Drops/recreates manged Identity
Set-AzureRmWebApp -AssignIdentity $false -ResourceGroupName "rg01" -Name "fa01" 
Set-AzureRmWebApp -AssignIdentity $true -ResourceGroupName "rg01" -Name "fa01" 

$current = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "rg01" -Name "fa01"
$objectId = $current.Identity.PrincipalId

#Add functionApp Identity to Contributor
$role = Get-AzureRmRoleDefinition -Name "Contributor"
New-AzureRMRoleAssignment -ObjectId $objectId -RoleDefinitionName "Contributor"  -Scope "/subscriptions/{subscription guid}"

#Assign functionApp Identity to AD Role 'Directory Readers'
$roleDefinition = Get-AzureADMSRoleDefinition -Filter "displayName eq 'Directory Readers'"
$roleAssignment = New-AzureADMSRoleAssignment  -RoleDefinitionId $roleDefinition.Id -PrincipalId $objectId  -ResourceScope "/"

#Assign functionApp Identity to AD Group
$group = Get-AzureADGroup  -Filter "DisplayName eq  'adgroup01'"
Add-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -RefObjectId $objectId
```

Comment: So why you did not say you just want to operate on specific groups in your question? If so, obviously the Owner of the group is enough.

Comment: You need do not need Groups Administrator to perform  ListAsync, just Directory Readers.

Comment: So why not add the group via object id? If you give the Directory Reader, it can read all the things in the directory, I remember you said Admin price will never be allowed in production?It is also an admin role.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the user-assigned identity is a service principal that is not associated with an AD App.

In this case, if you want to give the R/W permissions for Azure AD Groups, you could give the admin role [`Groups administrator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#groups-administrator-permissions) to it directly.

Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `Roles and administrators`  -> select `Groups administrator` -> `Add assignments` -> search for the identity name and add it.

Comment: Admin price will never be allowed in production

Comment: @jlo-gmail If so, there is no other way. Unless you use your own ad app, then you can give the api permission.BTW, I think Directoy.Readwrite.All is more than group admin, why this will be allowed?